# Two actions for tap in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

Two actions for tap in tableview!

I have a question about tapping in tableview. Can I set secondary action on tap ? 
1. tap (default). 
2. I tap and hold the selected cell for 2-3 seconds and an alternative action is performed.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, you need to add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in your `cell.contentView` and handle that event, your 1 event "Normal Tap event" will be triggered by `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` default method while the hold event will be triggered by the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

**Example of cell implementation**

```
import UIKit

class LongPressTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var longPressGesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer?
    var longPressClosure : (()->Void)?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func setupWithClosure(closure:@escaping (()->Void)) {
        self.longPressClosure = closure
        if(longPressGesture == nil) {
            longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressAction(gesture:)))
            longPressGesture!.minimumPressDuration = 2
            self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture!)
        }
    }



    @objc func longPressAction(gesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began){
                self.longPressClosure?()
        }
     }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**TableView DataSource && Delegate example implementation**

```
extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LongPressTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? LongPressTableViewCell{
            cell.setupWithClosure {
                //LongPress action
                debugPrint("LongPress")
            }
            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        debugPrint("Tap Action")
    }
}
```